# Save a dark mode checkbox toggle to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, local-storage

On my website I have a checkbox, which toggles between a default light theme and a dark one. If the page is set to dark mode and refreshed, the theme is switched back to light mode. Is there a way to save the visitors decision, so the page stays in dark mode on refresh? This is the code I currently have:

```js
const chk = document.getElementById('chk');

chk.addEventListener('change', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #353535;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
        <div class="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
            <label class="label" for="chk">
        </div>
        <h1>website text</h1>
```

I realise it might be a simple answer, but i am new to web development, and am struggling to find answers myself. Thank in advance you for all your help.

Comment: You are using any language to program or only html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #353535;
  text-align:right;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
</style>

<title>Dark mode to Local Storage</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
            <label class="label" for="chk">Turn On Dark Mode</label>
        </div>
        <h1>Website Content</h1>
        
<script>
const chk = document.getElementById('chk');

chk.addEventListener('click', () => {
  chk.checked?document.body.classList.add("dark"):document.body.classList.remove("dark");
  localStorage.setItem('darkModeStatus', chk.checked);
});

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  if(localStorage.getItem('darkModeStatus')=="true"){
    document.body.classList.add("dark"); 
    document.getElementById('chk').checked = true;
  }
});
</script>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 This works for me just fine. How would you do this if you are grabbing  the id/class of the body here ``document.body.classList.add("dark"):document.body.classList.remove("dark");``

Answer (score 1):

The **localStorage** and **sessionStorage** properties allow saving `key/value` pairs in a web **browser**.

The **localStorage** object stores data with **no expiration date**. The data will **not be deleted** when the browser is **closed** and will be available the next day, week, or year.

---

To store value select checkbox to store in local storage. Whenever to open the page to check the value store or not.

Your case you try this....

> **StackOverflow snippet note store localStorage so Copy this code to your file.**

---

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
  
    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
        toggleSwitch.checked = true;
         document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    }
}

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
         document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    }
    else {        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
          localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
           document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    }    
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```css
body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #353535;
}

body.dark {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
    <label class="label" for="chk">
</div>
<h1>website text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example here. Use `localStorage.setItem()` to store a value in local storage. You can use any method to retrieve data from the input. Here I am simply using a form.

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {
  const formElem = document.getElementById('dark-mode');
  const formData = new FormData(formElem);
  const darkModeState = !!formData.get('toggler');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', darkModeState);
}
```

```html
<form id="dark-mode">
  <input type="checkbox" name="toggler"> Use darkmode
  <br/>
  <button type="button" onClick="toggleDarkMode()">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first define a variable and define the localstorage as it's value ( it is better to check the local storage before sitting the value  ) as down :

```
let DarkMode = localStorage.getItem('DarkMode');
if(DarkMode == null) {
   localStorage.setItem('DarkMode', 'false');
}
```

then make it true when user check the box
and update it in localstorage

```js
let DarkMode = localStorage.getItem('DarkMode');
if(DarkMode == null) {
   localStorage.setItem('DarkMode', 'false');
}

const chk = document.getElementById('chk');

chk.addEventListener('change', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    if (DarkMode == false) {
       DarkMode = true;
       localStorage.setItem('DarkMode' , true)
       console.log(DarkMode);
    } else {
       DarkMode = false;
       localStorage.setItem('DarkMode' , false)
       console.log(DarkMode);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #353535;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
    <label class="label" for="chk">
</div>
<h1>website text</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

let darkMode = false;

If user checked change variable to true
And then set the variable in local storage.

i.e

LocalStorage.setItem('darkTheme', true) ;

And then get the variable using localStorage.getItem(darkTheme')